# Facing Issues In Notification using Angularjs on click of the button

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and UI dev too and I have tried to implement a functionality of disabling the button on-click of it and showing a message on page e.g "In progress" and after 3 secs button should get enabled with a different message e.g "Completed".

Button is getting disabled on click but and not showing notification "In Progress"on-click instead showing notification "Complete"after 3 secs.

I have seen this similar kind of problem solved before in this forum but not able to figure out missing logic in my code ............kindly please help

MY HTML:

Analysis

In Progress  

Complete

Controller:

```
  $scope.isDisabled=false;
  $scope.showNotification=false;
  $scope.isEnabled=true;
  $scope.completeNotification=false; 

  $scope.showNext=function(){

       $scope.isDisabled=true;
       $scope.showNotification=true;
       $scope.buttonWait();



$scope.buttonWait = function() {
    $timeout($scope.isEnabled = true, $scope.showNotification = false, $scope.completeNotification = true, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Adding again html part::<div>
 <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-xl" style="margin-bottom:4px;white-space: normal;" data-ng-click="showNextWidget();" ng-disabled="isDisabled">Analysis    </button>
       
      <p class="notification-btn" ng-show="showNotification">System has started to explore the input data. Please wait until further notification!</p>   
       
      <p class="notification-btn-complete" ng-hide="showNotification" ng-show="completeNotification" ng-disabled="isEnabled">Please continue with the next process!</p>
    </div>

Comment: Please update the question with the code you wrote in comment. Can't read here

Comment: Or maybe even add a plunker pls.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.isEnabled = true;
  // ...
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Mikko, your syntax seems to be wrong. it should be like

```
$scope.buttonWait = function() {
 $timeout(function() { 
   $scope.isEnabled = true, 
   $scope.showNotification = false, 
   $scope.completeNotification = true
  }), 3000);
};
```

sample plnkr link [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e3RiyB06qfTm5FoHnIwh?p=preview)